# Insert new item using Web API AngularJS with model class

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have created an application using AngularJS and Web API. I am able to insert country record using parameters in web api and angular js. But it is not working when I use model class to pass the value between Web API and Angular JS.

Here is the Country class:

```
public class Country
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Country id
    /// </summary>
    public int ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of country
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Status
    /// </summary>
    public int Status { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// CreatedDate
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// CreatedUser
    /// </summary>
    public int CreatedUser { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updated Date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updated User
    /// </summary>
    public int UpdatedUser { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the CountryController.cs for web api service definition,

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Country/UpdateCountry")]
    public bool UpdateCountry(Country country)
    {
        var uttCountry = UserDefinedTableTypeGenerator.GetCountry(country);
        var parameters = new[]
        {
            new Parameter("@Country", uttCountry)
        };
        return CommonContext.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar<long>("[dbo].[spUpdateCountry]", parameters.ToArray(), storedProcedure: true) > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

CountryController.js file,

```
(function () {
angular.module("HRMSApplication").controller("countrycontroller", ["$scope", "$filter","$http", "countryservice", function ($scope, $filter,$http, countryservice) {

    $scope.add = function (Country) {
        alert('controller save');

     var data = {

            Name: Country.Name

        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/HrmsApi/api/Country/UpdateCountry', data).success(function (data) {
            $scope.returnValue = data;
            alert('hi');
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving person! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
```

}

Country.html code,

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

        <div class="pull-right icon-btn"><a class="btn btn-info" href="country_view.html"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View</a></div>

        <div class="box-body col-md-6 center-form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Country Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Country.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div><!--form group-->

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Status</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                </div>
            </div><!--form group-->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <a href="employee.html" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="add(Country)" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </form>
```

While passing Country model through Web API service from AngularJS control is not happening.

Comment: Shouldn't you send the whole object? Why would you only send part of it? Also have you verified that `Country` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, property names from the JavaScript side need to be lowercase.

```
var data = {
    name: Country.Name
};
```

instead of

```
var data = {
    Name: Country.Name
};
```

You should set some breakpoints so you can see what IS happening compared to what you think out to be happening.

Does the WEBAPI get called at all?  Does it have any data?  What errors come back, if any?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your replay. I have tried with lowercase, still no hope. I am not sure that the webAPI service code is correct or not. Thanks, Aneesh